# DbCommand - how to supply provider-specific properties

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

On ye olde ADODB.Command object there was a Properties member that took 'provider specific' properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675257(v=vs.85).aspx

How can this be achieved in ADO.NET?

Specifically, I'm looking to supply a Timeout for the ADSDSOObject provider (LDAP) as we have almost a gazillion objects in our AD and many queries timeout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: [DbCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry I should have said. Yes. It seems to make no difference so I wondered if, being provider-specific, that the provider was not reading or being fed this info.